# Editing questions when you have 2000 reputation

Tags: support

Currently anyone can edit a question or answer, but if you have less than 2000 reputation your edit has to be reviewed. I know for a fact that if the edit is accepted you gain +2 reputation. My question is once you gain 2000 reputation, if you make an edit, it is automatically accepted. But would you automatically get +2 reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only get +2 reputation when you edit a post if:

- Your edit is **suggested** - i.e. you have less than 2k rep (when editing posts posts) or less than 20k rep (for editing tag wikis)
- You have earned less than 1000 rep total from suggested edits

If you have more than the required rep, or you have already earned 1k rep from suggested edits, then you will not get +2 rep.

Otherwise 2k+ users could infinitely farm reputation by making multiple tiny changes to posts (2k+ users have no min. character limit on edits) without anyone stopping them.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge - and sadly, that is - **no**.